# Keyman Android custom layout

Tags: unicode, keyboard, keyman, keyman-developer

I have created an app with Android Studio that needs a custom keyboard with only a few letters and numbers.  I can create alternate keys in the Keyman development IDE but I can't find how to change what is displayed on the virtual keyboard buttons.

Thanks in advance
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to add the "Touch-Optimised Keyboard" feature in the [Details tab](https://help.keyman.com/developer/current-version/context/keyboard-editor#details) in the Keyman Developer IDE.

[image: Features section in Details tab]

Once you have added this, the [Touch Layout tab](https://help.keyman.com/developer/current-version/context/keyboard-editor#toc-touch-layout-tab) will be added which allows you to change the layout for Android (and iOS) devices.

[image: Touch Layout Editor]